# Caesar cipher, wrap around when char's are >'z'

Tags: c++, encryption

I was here earlier and got a hand adding to characters ASCII references to increment the cipher shift on each letter. However I have no idea how to fix the problem of characters being higher than 'z'.

Can someone give me a hint towards how to wrap around when the characters reach the end of the alphabet. I don't expect anyone to do my work for me, of course.

```
char decrypt(char letter)
{
int increment = 9;
if(letter == ' ')
{
    return letter;
}
letter += increment;
return letter;
}

int main()
{
char message[446]; int i = 0; char space = ' ';
ifstream in("encryptedText.txt");
if(in.getline(message, 446))
{
    while(message[i])
    {
            cout << decrypt(tolower(message[i])) << endl;
            i++;
    }
}
else
{cout << "Can't read file" << endl;}
cout << endl;  
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @Marobri... it's worth bearing in mind that the ascii characters can be directly translated into digits. It would help you if you thought about them as digits... google search for ascii table and you can see the universally applicable numeric values that you can use for future "letter maths".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modulo operation is your friend. Whenever integers form a ring instead of a sequence, a modulo operation can be applied, like:

```
5 % 4 == 17 % 4
```

You need to compute this in the integer space relative to `'a'`, of course, subtracting `'a'` appropriately.